# Proving that $(p → q) → (p ∧ r) ≡ p ∧ (q → r)$ without a truth table

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Need help, new to truth tables and laws of logic (reading through Discrete Mathematics currently).

What I need is to show that $(p → q) → (p ∧ r) ≡ p ∧ (q → r)$ by using Laws of Logic. Any help would be great--I cannot find the relevant section in my book and I am unsure of the best approach to this kind of problem.

Comment: Start by using that $t \to u \equiv \neg t \vee u$.

Comment: not even sure about that stuff... :s reading through book and don't see anything in the section on t → u ≡ ¬t ∨ u listed - t / u so im confused as is :/ sorry like I said new to it...

Comment: Using laws of logics is just like simplifying any other mathematical expression, although you use v or ^ symbols. So as Stefan suggested, simply rewrite the LHS but replacing p $\rightarrow$ q as $~p v q$ and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working through Discrete Mathematics (which text?), then surely whatever section concerns logic is where you will find laws related to what you are trying to prove here. I will give a proof below and list the laws in the margin, but it will be completely useless unless you verify it through your own book (if you do not understand the proof, then it obviously does you no good at all). With that in mind, see if you can follow the proof outline below:
\begin{align}
(p\to q)\to(p\land r)&\equiv \neg(\neg p\lor q)\lor(p\land r)\tag{material implication}\\[1em]
&\equiv (p\land\neg q)\lor(p\land r)\tag{De Morgan}\\[1em]
&\equiv p\land(\neg q\lor r)\tag{distributivity}\\[1em]
&\equiv p\land(q\to r).\tag{material implication}
\end{align}